# Assigning Vue/JS element ref to a const with Typescript

Tags: html, typescript, vue.js, vuejs3, vue-composition-api

I have a template with one form element and one button element:

```html
  <button
    type="submit"
    id="ms_sign_in_submit"
    ref="submitButton"
    class="btn btn-lg btn-primary w-100 mb-5">
  </button>
```

I have `const` called `submitButton` in the script.

```
const submitButton = ref<HTMLButtonElement | null>(null);
```

Somehow the `submitButton` element (`id="ms_sign_in_submit"`) gets assigned/inherited(?) to `submitButton.value`, but I don't understand how. `submitButton` element is never explicitly assigned to `submitButton` `const`.

Comment: It would be surprising if this happened without the mention of `submitButton` in the code, but here it is. This is exactly what `ref="submitButton"` is responsible for.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Vue **automatically** assigns a template ref to the `ref` with a matching name returned from the `setup()` hook, like in the following code:

```html
<template>
  <button ref="submitButton">Submit</button>
</template>     

<script lang="ts">
import { defineComponent, ref } from 'vue'

export default defineComponent({
  setup() {
    const submitButton = ref<HTMLButtonElement | null>(null);
    return { submitButton }
  }            /* automatically assigned to template ref of same name */
})
</script>
```

The template ref assignment is not something you would explicitly do yourself.

It also sounds like there might be some confusion about `const`. Even though the `submitButton` is a `const` object, its `value` property can still be modified. This is true for all `const` objects that aren't [frozen (`Object.freeze()`)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/freeze) or declared [with `const` assertions (`as const`)](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-3-4.html#const-assertions) in TypeScript ([demo](https://tsplay.dev/wjk9vN)).

Comment: " /* automatically assigned to template ref of same name */"

Huge thank you.  Super helpful.  That seamed to be the behavior, but it was not intuitive how that connection was being made.  All the Vue basics describe refs as being a way to reference DOM elements directly.  Is this automatic assignment behavior in the setup() just something you have to know, or am I missing some fundamental know-how here?

Comment: It's actually [documented](https://vuejs.org/guide/essentials/template-refs.html#accessing-the-refs), but you have to toggle the Composition API docs (flip the switch in the top left corner), which reveals: "To obtain the reference with Composition API, we need to declare a ref with the same name".